# Exactly how much of what did General Benjamin Butler seize from the Netherlands Consulate in New Orleans on May 10th, 1862?

Tags: american-civil-war, netherlands, gold

There seems to be some conflicting reports over whether or not the amount was cash or specie, and exactly how much of it was seized.

Comment: -1 until you name and quote from those "conflicting reports"

Answer (score 3):

The book [Private and Official Correspondence of Gen. Benjamin F. Butler](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ly0OAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA385&lpg=PA385&dq=Benjamin%20Butler%20seize%20from%20the%20Netherlands%20Consulate&source=bl&ots=p845VaCnDV&sig=9MoLV1R12VOyn066iUbs7PkXnwk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAgfqo4OLTAhVK_IMKHRDWDHgQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=Benjamin%20Butler%20seize%20from%20the%20Netherlands%20Consulate&f=false) contains a copy of documents concerning the *return*, on sept 23 1862, of the material confiscated from the consul Amadie Conturie.

> I have the honor to report that on the morning of Sept 23rd 1862 I
>   delivered to Amadie Conturie of New Orleans Consul of the Netherlands
>   at the Master s office in the Customhouse one hundred and sixty kegs
>   marked H & C said to contain five thousand Mexican Silver Dollars each
>   making the sum of Eight Hundred Thousand Dollars.
>   Also one tin box
>   sealed marked Prean & Conturie containing valuable papers an inventory
>   of which was taken there and then by said Conturie taking at the same
>   time his acknowledgment for the coin endorsed on said communication
>   and his receipt for the contents which I herewith transmit. 
>   On the
>   following day Sept 24th 1862 by your order I received from said
>   Conturie a keg supposed to be one of said one hundred and sixty and
>   weighing two hundred and eighty nine pounds 289 and gave him in
>   exchange therefor an open keg containing Mexican Silver dollars which
>   weighed Three Hundred Twelve and one half 312 pounds I have the honor
>   to be 
>  
>   *Very Respectfully Your obedient Servant* P Haggerty *Capt* & ADC

and the reciept:

> *From Amadie Conturie* Received New Orleans Sept 23rd 1862 of Capt P Haggerty ADC to Major General Butler and by direction of Brig Gen GF
>   Shepley Military Governor of Louisiana One Hundred and Sixty kegs
>   marked H & C and said to contain each Five Thousand Mexican Silver
>   Dollars making in all Eight Hundred Thousand Mexican Dollars and one
>   tin box containing valuable papers sealed Amadie Couturie

So it appears the amount was $800,000. Transported in 160 kegs,each containing 5000 Mexican Silver Dollars. It is not readily apparent what the last paragraph of the first letter is concerning, but may have been a correction of some sort.